# ASP.NET EF6 DB-First Model parameter

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, stored-procedures, model

I have a stored procedure called, "SP", which returns a custom table with values of type Double.

In Asp.net environment, EF6 is applied along with a model to store the result set that "SP" returns. Thus, it has only 1 field which is a `Nullable` Double.

The issue is the "SP" does not always return a Double. Sometimes it's a Double, sometimes it's a Decimal and sometimes it's a Long.

An Exception is thrown as the model expects the stored procedure to return a Double.

How do I solve this without modifying the stored procedure?

Comment: Why is modifying the stored procedure a problem? because your changes in the model might get overwritten by the entity framework mapper when the next time your function import is created....

Comment: it is not a problem if the database part is handled by me (i think problem can be solved if i declared the type of the parameter first for the table). the problem is the database is not managed by me thus i cannot modify it directly.